# Use of もともと in a self- introduction 自己紹介

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is it proper or acceptable to say "僕はもともとNew Yorkから来まして。。。" during a formal self-introduction? This would be in the presence of superiors. Or does anyone know a better way to begin a 自己紹介?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not it is appropriate to use 「元々{もともと}」 in your self-introduction would depend on how you ended up at your present place of residence.

> Straight from New York:

If you just came to your current city/country, etc. ***straight from New York*** where you were born and raised, it is ***not*** very natural to use 「元々」.  You might say:

「ニューヨーク出身{しゅっしん}です。」 or

「ニューヨークから参{まい}りました。」 (You used 「来{く}る」, but it is informal, so I used 「参る」.)

Disclaimer: It is not a crime to use 「元々」 in this case, but in a place like this, that is how I would answer your question.

> Via at least one other place:

If you have lived in at least one other place prior to living where you live now after originally living in New York for x years, it is appropriate to use 「元々」.  You could say:

「**元々**ニューヨーク出身です。」

and you may tell what other places you have lived before coming to your current place.

**IMPORTANT: Drop the first-person pronoun.  They know who you are talking about.**

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

> （もともと）ニューヨーク出身で。。。

Since new york is well known. Else I would have specified the country first.

I don't think there is anything wrong with もともと in this scenario. It is optional and quite neutral. It won't impress them, but it won't be impolite either. Although I wouldn't worry too much. I doubt they will be so picky if you are a foreigner anyway.